# Changing keymapping in SDL program (aDosbox)

Tags: sdl, dosbox

aDosbox is hard-coded to use a keymapping suitable for the T-Mobile G1.

I'm using a G2, and that is a fairly inconvenient mapping.

I'm completely new to android development, sadly.

I've been poring over the code, and have managed to substitute a few characters, but I think I must be missing something pretty basic.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

How can I even find the keycodes/scancodes for the built-in G2 keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I even find the keycodes/scancodes for the built-in G2 keyboard?

Whip up a small [`SDL_WaitEvent()`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_WaitEvent) loop and print out all the [`SDL_KEYUP`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_KeyboardEvent) events.